# Create a video with 5 images with fade in/out, zoom pan, and slide left/right

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have to create a video with 5 different images 3 sec for each with the following sequence

1. Fade Out
2. Fade In
3. Zoom
4. Slide Left
5. Slide Right

I do not know about sliding filter command and also zooming is not working correctly.

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img001.png \
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img002.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img003.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img004.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img005.png \
-c:v libx264 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v0]; \
 [1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v1]; \
 [2:v]zoompan=z='zoom+0.001':d=10:s=1200x478[v2]; \
 [3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v3]; \
 [4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

Comment: Crossposting the [same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1053346/create-a-video-with-5-images-with-fade-in-out-zoom-pan-and-slide-left-right) to multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged, and your question is off-topic here because it is not a programming question.